# jQuery search for nearest number

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm creating a form where you can choose between different sizes of paper, everything working well and I've made a search form in jQuery that looks in the text() of a div to find matching formats. In example: there's a size 105 x 148 and if I type "105" in `#searchformat` it hide()s all other divs without "105".

```
$('#searchformat').keyup(function() {
    $('.awspc-image-selection-box').hide();
    $('.awspc-image-selection-box-content .awspc-image-selection-box-content-label').each(function() {
        if($(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '').indexOf(""+text+"") != -1 ) {
            $(this).closest('.awspc-image-selection-box').show();
        }
    });
});
```

This works great. There's just one thing I can't seem to get working, I want to have the ability if you type in the input field for example "104" that it will also show the divs with "105" in it. With a margin of +- 5.

The field where I need to search in is `$('.awspc-image-selection-box-content-label').text()` and I already tried it with a function having `return Math.round(x.match(/\d+/) / text) * text;` but this looks for the nearest number and the problem here also is that the value of the field is like this: `<div class="awspc-image-selection-box-content-label"> 38.1 x 8 mm </div>`

HTML:

```
<div class="awspc-image-selection-box" data-value="7" data-id="aws_price_calc_45" data-substrate="">          
    <div class="awspc-image-selection-box-content">
        <img style="width: ; height: " src="/uploads/woocommerce-placeholder-768x768.png" alt="170">
        <div class="awspc-image-selection-box-content-label">38.1 x 8 mm</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So how can I in example search for "39" and it will show me the div having "38"?

Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE**

I figured some working code out but the only problem now is how I can retrieve what the closest() div is from the result...

```
var tooSearchFor = $('.awspc-image-selection-box-content-label').text();
tooSearchFor   = tooSearchFor.split('\n');
for(var i = 0; i < tooSearchFor.length; i++)
tooSearchFor[i] = parseInt(tooSearchFor[i]) || 0;
var goalFormat = textInputSearch;
var closestFormat = null;
$.each(tooSearchFor, function(){
     if (closestFormat == null || Math.abs(this - goalFormat) < Math.abs(closestFormat - goalFormat)) {
     closestFormat = this;
}
});

 console.log ('Closest format:' + closestFormat); // outputs the closest found number
```

How can I retrieve the div where `closestFormat` is found in  the array...?

Comment: Could you fill this out to make a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? That'd make it easier for us to help you out. You've got a good start already - just flesh it out a tiny bit and it could be great!

Comment: I've updated the post with some extra code I produced but now I'm facing the last problem find the correct div...